# Predicate chaining question

Tags: java, guava

Below is the object structure -

- class `A`  has a collection of class `B`
- class `B` has one to one mapping with class `C`
- I have a predicate `P` defined in `C`

Requirement : Return a list of `B` which have atleast one of the elements of `C`'s Predicate `P` return `true` .

My current solution has a for loop. I was wondering if this can be done without using a for loop.

Comment: Can you give an example of your current `for` loop solution? I'm not sure I follow you.

Answer (score 4):

Why does it matter where the Predicate is defined?  Do you mean that it's define **on** C?

```
// You already have Predicate<C> defined somewhere
Predicate<C> csPredicate = new Predicate<C>() {
    public boolean apply(C c) {
        return someComputationOn(c);
    }
};

Iterables.filter(A.getIterableOfB(), 
    Predicates.compose(
        csPredicate, 
        new Function<B, C>() {
            @Override
            public C apply(B b) {
                return b.getC();
            }
}));
```

My answer is very similar to sMoZely (+1) except i'm using Iterables.filter() and composing the Predicates instead of using Collections2 but the idea is the same.  I may also be missing something in the question...

Comment: Thats a good solution too... I didn't know about the compose function.

Comment: Need to implement `Predicate<C>`

Comment: @Ray - yes you're quite right - i left it like that because the OP seemed to have this already so i left it as a placeholder - i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly ... can't you just create a Predicate for B that calls the Predicate for C?

i.e.  in B ...

```
new Predicate<B>() {
  @Override
  public boolean apply(B record) {
    return new PredicateOverC().apply(record.getC())
  }
}
```

And then in A you can just use Collections2.filter over the collection of B and this new predicate?